# Python: Different result when performing division vs. floor division when dividing <0.1

Tags: python, division

Accidentally I stumbled upon the following difference. The division 50/0.02 returns a float:

```
2500.0
```

However a floor division 50//0.02 returns - as it seems to me - a wrong answer:

```
2499.0
```

Can anybody explain how this difference is caused?

Comment: `>>> format(0.02, '.58f') > '0.0200000000000000004163336342344337026588618755340576171875'` is a good starting point for the explanation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fascinating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to python's floating point precision problems. `0.02` is actually as Martijn Pieters suggested `0.02000000000000000041633363423443370265886187553405762` and so this when divided by 50 gives a value like `2499.99999999999994795875`, and with floor division, this value is floored and becomes `2499`.

Have a look at [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) to have a better understanding about floating point numbers in python

Comment: This answer doesn't address why the floor division result differs from the float result, which is *exactly* 2500.0.

Comment: There is no such thing as "python's floating point precision problems". These problems belong to all IEEE floats, no matter if we use them in C, Python, Java or wherever.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to say just python, but python also has the problem that most programming languages have and I just wanted to make sure the OP understood.